# Transforming the Book of Artifacts to 5E

Tags: dnd-5e, adnd-2e, conversion

Where can I find a reference, preferably online, to help convert the Advanced D&D Book of Artifacts to 5E? If nothing else, just converting Appendix B. One of the big things is finding spell/effect equivalents.

The only written materials I own are 5E PHB and MM and Advanced D&D Book of Artifacts. The Book of Artifacts obviously references Advanced D&D, so for me to convert it, the help I need isn't a direct conversion guide but rather spell/effect definitions from the earlier D&D that are referred to in the Book of Artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

**There are no official conversion guides**

WOTC has not released any guidelines for converting materials from previous editions. The DMG may have something along those lines when it releases in December.

Comment: Perhaps further explanation is needed. The only written materials I own are 5E PHB and MM and Advanced D&D Book of Artifacts. The Book of Artifacts obviously references Advanced D&D, so for me to convert it, the help I need isn't a direct conversion guide but rather spell/effect definitions from the earlier D&D that are referred to in the Book of Artifacts.

Comment: @Korack If what you need is not a *conversion* guide but a guide at all to what AD&D spell names mean, that has been published: the AD&D *Player's Handbook*. (They're cheap on eBay.) There are also retroclones, free and paid, that define the spells more-or-less the same, but naming and linking them all is beyond the scope of a comment.

Comment: @Korack Can we refine/clarify the question, perhaps? Right now it asks for help converting the *BoA* material. From this comment exchange though, it sounds like you just need a reference for what the original spells do, and then you'd be able to handle the conversion fine from there. Is that right? If so, I don't think anyone is grasping that from the question currently, and it could be edited to be more useful to your needs.

Comment: Sounds like the players guide should do me. I can always ask about specific mechanics that might not be covered, if needed.